# Llamar a un método desde dentro de sí mismo

Tags: php, funciones

Me gustaría saber si puedo llamar un método desde dentro de sí mismo.

Por ejemplo:

```php
miMetodo($var1, $var2 = '') {
    miMetodo('only', 'one');
}

miMetodo("dos");
```

Claro está que manejo el flujo y no se forma un infinito, pero es que solo se ejecuta una vez, que es cuando la llamo desde afuera.

Comment: se llaman metodos recursivos, aqui te dejo un link donde lo explica http://mialtoweb.es/recursividad-en-php/#:~:text=La%20recursividad%20en%20PHP%20se%20da%20cuando%20una,parecido%20a%20esto%20de%20forma%20muy%20esquematica%3A%201

Comment: Acabo de leer tu pregunta con más detenimiento al editarla y me he dado cuenta que dices que "solo se ejecuta una vez". ¿A qué te refieres con eso? ¿Lo haces desde dentro de una clase? ¿Desde el mismo o diferentes espacios de nombres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La respuesta rápida es que sí, puedes hacerlo.

A este tipo de funciones se les llama [funciones recursivas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n) y al hecho de hacerlo se llama recursión.

El problema que estás sufriendo es muy común en las funciones recursivas que no tienen un **caso base**. El caso base es aquél en el que la función no se llama a sí misma y comienza la salida de la recursión.

Para que una función recursiva esté construida adecuadamente ha de poder llegar al caso base en un número finito de recursiones.

En tu caso el caso base podría ser haber definido el segundo parámetro:

```
function miMetodo($var1, $var2 = '') {
    echo "Var1: $var1", PHP_EOL;
    if (empty($var2)) {
        miMetodo('only', 'one');
    } else {
        echo "Var2: $var2", PHP_EOL;
    }
}

miMetodo("dos");
```

El resultado sería:

```
Var1: dos
Var1: only
Var2: one
```